# How can I fix corrupted shortcut icons?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, graphics-card, desktop-icons

One of my computers was showing really bad graphics problems, not only in Windows but also in the BIOS. I replaced the graphics card and most problems went away - except the .LNK shortcut icons in Windows Explorer and on the desktop (see attached image).

**What is causing this corruption, and how can I fix it? How do I get the icons to appear properly again?**

It seems that the icon rendering itself is broken, not the actual ICO image. I tested this by choosing different icons for some of the shortcuts. The effect was a less damaged icon, but damaged nevertheless. The best case was like the center-left icon in the image: "Neu starten".

This is Windows XP Pro SP3, on an nVidia GeForce 5500FX 256MB card. Previous card was ATI Radeon 9800XXL.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the XP Icon Cache (*Iconcache.db*) is damaged, try deleting this file

> C:\Documents and Settings\ [Your Name] \Local Settings\Application Data\Iconcache.db

as described [here](http://smallvoid.com/article/windows-icon-cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its because the image cache was corrupt. It's a file called Thumbs.db and its hidden. Select show hidden and system files in directory properties and then delete Thumbs.db in any folders with corrupt icons.